# WCF: 500 ошибка

Tags: c#, http, wcf

Добрый день!

Я пытался гуглить по этому вопросу, но так и не понял.
Ситуация:

На сервере размещен WCF-сервис, и некоторые пользователи не смогли его использовать, они получали **500  ошибку**

Лог IISа показал следующее:

```
2016-02-22 08:27:34 172.31.7.15 POST /Service1.svc/SoapBufferedCert - 4454 - 192.168.100.36 - - 500 0 0 9157
2016-02-22 08:27:42 172.31.7.15 POST /Service1.svc/SoapBufferedCert - 4454 - 192.168.100.36 - - 500 0 0 15
2016-02-22 08:28:13 172.31.7.15 POST /Service1.svc/SoapBufferedCert - 4454 - 192.168.100.36 - - 500 0 0 15
```

Причем сам сервис сразу после ошибок включился в работу и начал исправно работать. Вот что я хочу узнать: **какие могут быть причины того, что сервис время от времени выдает 500ую ошибку?**

Спасибо

**UPD**
Конфиг:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <client />

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CertCoreBehavior" name="Service1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="SoapBufferedCert" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityBinding" contract="Service1.IService1" />       
      </service>
    </services>

      <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <!--  Сертификаты  -->
        <behavior name="CertCoreBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="10000" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" includeWindowsGroups="false" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecurityBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
          <!--<security mode="None">         
          </security>-->
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: 500 это внутренняя  ошибка сервера, возможно пользователи отправляют не корректные сообщения (возможно там есть данные из-за которых "ломается" БД).

Comment: Глянул, 172.31.0.0 это тоже под интранет. А то что они в разных сетях, на маршрутах все правильно настроенно?

Comment: т.к. севрис выдает ошибку 500 достаточно редко, то я думаю что правильно

Answer (score 1):

500я ошибка выдается в случае любого исключения. Больше информации должно быть в теле сообщения, которое у вас не сохранилось.

Тут есть два варианта.

Во-первых, можно настроить логи на стороне сервиса. Это можно сделать как простейшим try-catch в каждом методе, так и создав свой OperationBehavior, который [подменит OperationInvoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183867.aspx).

Во-вторых, можно попросить пользователей сохранять пришедшие им SOAP Faults и посылать вам. Глупый рабочий процесс - но для отладки сгодится. Тут, скорее всего, надо будет настроить [отправку трассировки стека в фоултах](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315680/4340086).

В дальнейшем, некоторые ошибки можно будет выделить в отдельные типизированные фоулты, которые прописываются в wsdl. Это делается с помощью атрибута [`FaultContractAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Т.е. в коде моего сервиса скорее всего необрабатываемое исключение?

Comment: @LeonardBertone Да. Только оно называется "необработанное". Есть и другие варианты, но этот - самый вероятный.

Comment: Мне скинули текст ошибки: "The requested service, 'https://host:port/Service1.svc/SoapBufferedCert' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information. "

Comment: Эта ошибка тоже может быть связана с необработанным исключением? Спасибо

Comment: Да, может быть - если это исключение в конструкторе. Но тут уже становится непонятно почему у вас сервис вообще работает. Лучше приведите секцию `system.serviceModel` из вашего `web.config`.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос и указал эту секцию из конфига

Comment: как Вы считаете ?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем конфиге не хватает вот такой настройки:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Если не поможет - настраивайте [`трассировку wcf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271597/4340086).

Comment: Общение с сервисом проходит по https. Ваша настройка не повредит этому? На МСДН aspNetCompatibilityEnabled пишет про http

Comment: Нет, не повредит.